# Chrome-only layout issue when using directives

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, angularjs-directive

## Summary

While working on an angular based single page app (Ushahidi's v3 frontend), we stumbled over the following issue. 
It occurs only in Chrome, not in Firefox (can't say anything about other browsers right now).

The problem is that an element (in our case: the login button) is not positioned correctly when we move its html into an directive (scenario 2), while it looks as expected when using the HTMl directly inside of the main page template (scenario 1).

The rendered HTML of the whole page is in both scenarios the same.

[image: screenshot showing the layout issue]

## Reproducing both scenarios

You can reproduce both scenarios easily within about 3 minutes via the following steps (first getting the app running, then describing how to see both scenarios):

### Quick app setup

- needs only to be done once for both the working and not working state

  - Prerequisites
  - have node/npm installed
  - have gulp and napa installed

    - `(sudo) npm install -g gulp napa`
  - `git clone https://github.com/spaudanjo/platform-client.git`
  - `cd platform-client`
  - `git fetch origin fix_T1107_chrome_layout_bug:fix_T1107_chrome_layout_bug`
  - `git checkout fix_T1107_chrome_layout_bug`
  - `(sudo) npm install`
  - `bower install`
  - `napa install`
  - `gulp --node-server --mock-backend`
  - open Chrome with `http://localhost:8080`

### Working state (scenario 1, without using directives)

- `git checkout ca99fdeb4613265063c0f481588c2e34ecd109ed`
- refresh Chrome
- make sure that the top right menu looks like expected (the Login button is on the same line as "Create" and "Workspace")

### Not working state (scenario 2, using directives)

- `git checkout 5fe22a68aea3c8cbf1497dc2c3c7f3d83ab822f3`
- refresh Chrome
- make sure that you recognize the layout issue (the Login button is not placed correctly; see attached screenshot)

## Changed files

- To easily see the affected files, here is the diff of the commit which moves the directives HTML back again to the main template:

  - https://github.com/spaudanjo/platform-client/commit/ca99fdeb4613265063c0f481588c2e34ecd109ed

Any hints/ideas?